# How to specify the original parameters without making any changes in the keyf function of the aggregation group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my starting simplified collection:

```
[{
  "_id" : ObjectId("577a598ecab5bb4a002c19da"),
  "user" : ObjectId("5775549f9fcaae26c9149026"),
  "expense" : 12.87,
  "created" : ISODate("2016-07-04T12:43:07.181Z")
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("577a598ecab5bb4a002c19db"),
  "user" : ObjectId("5775549f9fcaae26c9149026"),
  "expense" : 12.87,
  "created" : ISODate("2016-07-06T12:10:07.181Z")
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("977a598ecai6bb4a002c19du"),
  "user" : ObjectId("6775539f9fciae26c9149027"),
  "expense" : 12.87,
  "created" : ISODate("2016-07-07T10:43:07.181Z")
},
....
]
```

I want to `group` and count all `users` for a specific day of the `created` parameter.

I'm trying this but it does not work:

```
db.getCollection('expenses').group({
            keyf: function(doc) {
               return { 
                   "day_created": doc.created.getDate(),
                   "user" : doc.user // or  "user" : 1
                }
            },
            cond: {},
            reduce: function (value, result) {
                result.total++;  
            },
            initial: {
                total: 0
            }
 });
```

Instead the individual groups work perfectly (for date):

```
db.getCollection('expenses').group({
            keyf: function(doc) {
               return { 
                   "day_created": doc.created.getDate()
                }
            },
            cond: {},
            reduce: function (value, result) {
                result.total++;  
            },
            initial: {
                total: 0
            }
 });
```

**Response**:

```
[
    {
        "day_created" : 17,
        "total" : 5385
    },
    {
        "day_created" : 18,
        "total" : 6338
    },
 ....
]
```

Instead the individual groups work perfectly (for user):

```
db.getCollection('tickets').group({
            key : {user : 1},
            cond: {},
            reduce: function (value, result) {
                result.total++;  
            },
            initial: {
                total: 0
            }
 });
```

**Response**:

```
[
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("5776f0143543e84a003d53bf"),
        "total" : 155
    },
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("577554a89fcaae26c914a8bd"),
        "total" : 494
    },
...
]
```

I'm using MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1. How do I make the group aggregation by using a calculated field and others do not ?

Comment: What's your expected output from the above sample documents?

Comment: My expected output : 

[
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("5776f0143543e84a003d53bf"),
        "day_created" : 17,
        "total" : 155
    },
    {
        "user" : ObjectId("577554a89fcaae26c914a8bd"),
        "day_created" : 17,
        "total" : 494
    },
...
]

Comment: Is that the expected result for the desired aggregation operation "group and count all users for a specific day of the created parameter."?

Comment: yes  "group and count all users for a specific day of the created parameter."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the group function, you can use the aggregation framework to get the desired aggregates. Consider running the following pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('expenses').aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "day_created": { 
                "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                    "date": "$created" 
                } 
            },
            "user": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "day_created": "$day_created",
                "user": "$user"
            },
            "total": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0
            "user": "$_id.user",
            "day_created": "$_id.day_created",
            "total": 1
        }
    }
])
```

---

In the above pipeline, the first **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** step will create the day_created field using the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** operator. The next **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline will then group the documents by the two keys, `user` and the newly created `day_created` field and calculate the aggregate using **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**.

The last **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step then reshapes the fields to output the desired JSON structure.

---

To address your question, you need to convert the `created` date to a date format that represents the day uniquely.

Try running the following:

```
db.getCollection('expenses').group({
    keyf: function(doc) {
        var month = '' + (doc.created.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + doc.created.getDate(),
        year = doc.created.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        var day_created = [year, month, day].join('-');
        return { 
            "day_created": day_created,
            "user" : doc.user 
        }
    },
    cond: {},
    reduce: function (value, result) {
        result.total++;  
    },
    initial: {
        total: 0
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks to this solution, but I would use the method

`db.collection.group()`

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you use `db.collection.group()` when the aggregation framework's `$group` works just as great, even more efficiently? Because `db.collection.group()` uses JavaScript, it is subject to a number of performance limitations. For most cases the `$group` operator in the aggregation pipeline provides a suitable alternative with fewer restrictions.

Comment: thanks for your answer , `now I'm using the aggregation` because the problem is not related to the syntax of the group , but the `size of my collection`

So : This work 

 return { 
                   "day_created": doc.created.getDate(),
                   "user" : doc.user // or  "user" : 1
                }

but i'v this error : 

[thread1] Error: group command failed: {
 "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "errmsg: \"group() can't handle more than 20000 unique keys\"",
 "code" : 2
}

Comment: That limitation is [**documented**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#limits-and-restrictions).